# For a matrix $F$ with more columns than rows, why is $F\cdot F^T$ invertible?

Tags: matrices

Assuming $F$ is a matrix with full rank but more columns than rows - why is $F\cdot F^T$ invertible?

Comment: What just happened?!

Comment: Invertible..."things"? You mean like a dog doing a rolling trick or a capsizing ship? Really...

Comment: Counter-example in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (see Ted's comment): $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ with $p$ columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to show the null space of $F F^T$ is $\{0\}$.

Suppose $F F^T x = 0$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
& x^T F F^T x = 0 \\
\implies & (F^T x)^T (F^T x) = 0\\
\implies & \|F^T x \|^2 = 0 \\
\implies & F^T x = 0 \\
\implies & x = 0.
\end{align*}

(Because $F^T$ is a skinny matrix with full rank, its null space is $\{0\}$.)

Comment: Assuming the matrix is over the real numbers, of course.  (Or other field where sum of nonzero squares cannot be zero.)